# ISOUtil.hex2byte appending 0 to left of my message

Tags: jpos

I am trying to create a JPOS web service using JAVA. Here is the code I am using.

```
            GenericPackager packager;
            packager = new GenericPackager("ISO_8583_1987.xml");
            org.jpos.util.Logger logger = new org.jpos.util.Logger();
            logger.addListener(new SimpleLogListener(System.out));
            ((LogSource)packager).setLogger(logger, "debug");
            ISOMsg isoMsg = new ISOMsg();
            isoMsg.setPackager(packager);
            isoMsg.unpack(b);
            printISOMessage(isoMsg);
```

The problem is all the way in the beginning on hex2byte method.

Length of everything up until Datafield 19 is in multiples of 2. Datafield 19 in my packager is IFB_NUMERIC with length 3. When I send message 02000000200000000000177 (Only datafield 19 set), hex2byte appends 0 to the left to make the message length even. Because of that, MTI comes as 0020 instead of 0200. This also messes up the bitmap since the bit set for field 17-18-19-20 is not bitmap for 21-22-23-24. As expected, when I run this, unpack method shows bit 23 as 017. This of course works fine if I send message 020000002000000000001770 (additional 0 at the end).

Should I be using something other than ISOUtil.hex2byte?

Comment: you can use the "pad" attribute in your ISO_8583_1987.xml file to 'false'.
<field id="xxx" pad="false" class="..." />

Comment: I tried that already for field 19 and MTI but it did not work. Should I be adding that to all 128 fields?

Comment: It was a different error. The message was actually ASCII but I was using ISOUtil.hex2byte to get the bytes. Replaced it with String.getBytes method and it works now. Thanks